# The structure of a struct?

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c)

can someone explain what's the difference between the following definitions of Struct

```
typedef struct
{
}GOOD;

&

struct GOOD
{
};

&

typedef struct tagGOOD
{
}GOOD;
```

My teacher uses the last example, but i don't really know why he uses a "tag" on the struct name (if is it's name), can someone make it clear please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structures are supposed to have a name:

```
struct StructName {
   // stuff
};
```

Typedefs take a type and give it a name:

```
typedef SomeType NameYouWannaGiveThatType;
```

The third example combines these.

The example is an unnamed struct, which some compilers get upset about.

The second example is a named struct but you traditionally couldn't refer to it without including the word struct.  *eg*

```
struct MyStruct {
    //...
};

MyStruct iffy;          // Not allowed in C, in my experience anyway
struct MyStruct good;   // No problem.
```

I haven't found this to be a problem in C++, but I'm sure there's people out there who know the C++ spec backwards and will give you a better answer.  Anyway, you get around this with typedef.

```
typedef MyStruct { /* etc */ } MyStruct;

MyStruct s;
```

Personally, and this is probably just a matter of style, I prefer to not to use the same name:

```
typedef MyStruct { /* etc */ } SMyStruct;
```

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++, any `struct` you declare with a name can be referred to as `struct GOOD`. You can also declare anonymous structs that do not have a name, as is done in the first example.

Any type can be `typedef`'d giving it an alternate name. In the first example, you're simply giving the name `GOOD` (without `struct`) to an anonymous struct. In the second example, your struct can only be accessed as `struct GOOD`. In the third, you can access it as either `GOOD` or `struct GOOD`.

All three options are legal, and which one to use is a matter of style.

Comment: The third example allows `struct tagGOOD` or `GOOD`, but not `struct GOOD`.

Comment: Thanks friend, it help a lot :) it really did.

Comment: +1 for being the first one and (almost) correct ...

Comment: The compiler doesn't complain about repeat the GOOD, can i repeat it? and i do need do put tagGood and Good? or it is just esthetic?

Comment: You can repeat it. They occupy different namespaces, meaning that a `typedef` and `struct` can have the same name. It's a matter of style.

Answer (score 2):

Throughout all the code I've read over the years, I've seen all of these variations used. I just checked in VS2010 and they seemed to be equivalent. What I can tell you though is that the typedef keyword used to be required in C, but no longer in C++.

Comment: Correct answer. Either the teacher is stuck in ~1992 when C and C++ diverged, or the teacher is teaching C and the question is mis-tagged.

Comment: The typedef was **not** required in C. It was (and is) used as a convenience, so that you don't have to say `struct foo` all the time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about C++, I believe typedef is not really needed.  The story in fact comes from C.

in C, when I declare

```
struct GOOD_STRUCT {
   ...
}
```

When I want to declare a variable of this struct, I need to do

```
struct GOOD_STRUCT good;
```

In order to have a better coding style and readability, people used to typedef on this:

```
typedef GOOD_STRUCT GOOD;
```

so you can do

```
GOOD good;
```

To combine it both, people used to do

```
typedef struct GOOD_STRUCT {
   ...
} GOOD;
```

or

```
typedef struct {
   ...
} GOOD;
```

However, in C++, it is no longer needed.  Once you have declare `struct GOOD`, you can already refer it by `GOOD` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Definition 1:

Defines an anonymous (empty) struct, and gives it a typedef of `GOOD`. This type can be referred to simply as `GOOD` in the future.

Definition 2:

Defines an (empty) struct named `GOOD`. In C and C++ this can be referred to as `struct GOOD`, and in C++ this can be referred to as `GOOD`.

Definition 3:

Defines an (empty) struct named `tagGOOD` and a typedef named `GOOD`. In C and C++ the struct can be referred to as both `struct tagGOOD` and `GOOD`, and in C++ this can be referred to as `tagGOOD`.

Definition 3 tends to be the most common in C code in my experience. People tend not to like anonymous structs very much, so they give the struct a name, but they also dislike using the `struct` keyword when referring to the type, so they give it a typedef as well. In C++ the typedef form is fairly pointless.